# how to make my wx GUI similar to the QT GUI

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

I using the wxFormbuilder to mimic a QT GUI design, but I always can not success to make a ideal result.

The question is related the alignment/layout. Can anyone give me a hand?

Because I can not attach files here, so I uploaded the wxFormbuilder project file and a qt-gui screenspot .png file to the links below.

If anyone has time, plz give me a guide.

The wxFrombuild project file and the qt_gui .png files are here. http://www.2shared.com/file/62BJYq2l/help_dlg.html  http://www.2shared.com/photo/uWl3XmRl/qt_GUI.html

Answer (score 0):

Your design is fairly complicated. I don't use wxFormbuilder, I like to set up my form manually, by "hard coding" the layout.

So before I explain how I would do it, here's a few advice:

- I would put the ok/cancel/help bar somewhere else (in a separate wxPanel, and put them together in the dialog at the end)
- I would move the test connect button on the ok/cancel/help bar.
- The test connect button is in an awful place at the moment in term of setting the layout
- (optionally) I would split the form between name/host/database and username/password since they represent some sub unit you can reuse somewhere else

Now here is how I would build the form. I let you implement the getValue and setValue.
Also you'll need to do something similar for the tool bar (using a `wxBoxSizer`) and put them together (using a `wxBoxSizer` again).

Also if you may want to use a `wxStaticBox`

```
class ConnectionEditor
  : wxPanel
{
public:
  ConnectionEditor(wxWindow* parent);
  //
  void getValue(ConnectionSettings&);
  void setValue(ConnectionSettings const&);
private:
  wxTextCtrl*     name_;
  wxTextCtrl*     host_;
  wxTextCtrl*     database_;
  wxTextCtrl*     username_;
  wxTextCtrl*     password_;
  wxCheckBox*     save_password_;
};


wxTextCtrl* CreateTextControl(wxWindow* parent)
{
  return new wxTextCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 20));
}

wxTextCtrl* CreateStaticText(wxWindow* parent, std::string const& text)
{
  return new wxStaticText(parent, wxID_ANY, text.c_str());
}


ConnectionEditor::ConnectionEditor(wxWindow* parent)
 : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
  this->name_ = CreateTextControl(this);
  this->host_ = CreateTextControl(this);
  this->database_ = CreateTextControl(this);
  this->username_ = CreateTextControl(this);
  this->password_ = CreateTextControl(this);
  this->save_password_ = new wxCheckBox(this, wxID_ANY, "on");
  //
  wxFlexGridSizer* sizer = new wxFlexGridSizer(6, 2, 5, ,5); // 6 rows, 2 cols, 5 spacing in between
  //
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Name"));
  sizer->Add(this->name_);
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Host"));
  sizer->Add(this->host_);
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Database"));
  sizer->Add(this->database_);
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Username"));
  sizer->Add(this->username_);
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Password"));
  sizer->Add(this->password_);
  sizer->Add(CreateStaticText(this, "Save Password"));
  sizer->Add(this->save_password_);
  //
  this->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
}
```